# Initiate subclasses from parent class

Tags: python, class, object-oriented-analysis

Suppose I have a list of inputs that will generate O objects, of the following form:

```
inps = [['A', 5], ['B', 2]]
```

and O has subclasses A and B. A and B each are initiated with a single integer --
5 or 2 in the example above -- and have a method `update(self, t)`, so I believe it makes sense to group them under an O superclass. I could complete the program with a loop:

```
Os = []
for inp in inps:
    if inp[0] == 'A':
        Os.append(A(inp[1]))
    elif inp[0] == 'B':
        Os.append(B(inp[1]))
```

and then at runtime,

```
for O in Os: O.update(t)
```

I'm wondering, however, if there is a more object oriented way to accomplish this. One way, I suppose, might be to make a fake "O constructor" outside of the O class:

```
def initO(inp):
    if inp[0] == 'A':
        return A(inp[1])
    elif inp[0] == 'B':
        return B(inp[1])

Os = [initO(inp) for inp in inps]
```

This is more elegant, in my opinion, and for all intensive purposes gives me the result I want; but it feels like a complete abuse of the class system in python. Is there a better way to do this, perhaps by initiating A and B from the O constructor?

EDIT: The ideal would be to be able to use

```
Os = [O(inp) for inp in inps]
```

while maintaining O as a superclass of A and B.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict) to map the names to the actual classes:

```
dct = {'A': A, 'B': B}

[dct[name](argument) for name, argument in inps]
```

Or if you don't want the list-comprehension:

```
dct = {'A': A, 'B': B}
Os = []
for inp in inps:
    cls = dct[inp[0]]
    Os.append(cls(inp[1]))
```

Answer (score 2):

In case you really want to create a (direct) subclass from within a parent class you could use the special [`__subclasses__`](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#class.__subclasses__) method:

```
class O(object):
    def __init__(self, integer):
        self.value = integer

    @classmethod
    def get_subclass(cls, subclassname, value):  
        # probably not a really good name for that method - I'm out of creativity...
        subcls = next(sub for sub in cls.__subclasses__() if sub.__name__ == subclassname)
        return subcls(value)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '{self.__class__.__name__}({self.value})'.format(self=self)

class A(O):
    pass

class B(O):
    pass
```

This acts like a factory:

```
>>> O.get_subclass('A', 1)
A(1)
```

Or as list-comprehension:

```
>>> [O.get_subclass(*inp) for inp in inps]
```

In case you want to optimize it and you know that you won't add subclasses during the programs progress you could put the subclasses in a dictionary that maps from `__name__` to the subclass:

```
class O(object):
    __subs = {}
    def __init__(self, integer):
        self.value = integer

    @classmethod
    def get_subclass(cls, subclassname, value):
        if not cls.__subs:
            cls.__subs = {sub.__name__: sub for sub in cls.__subclasses__()}
        return cls.__subs[subclassname](value)
```

You could probably also use `__new__` to implement that behavior or a metaclass but I think a `classmethod` may be more appropriate here because it's easy to understand and allows for more flexibility.

In case you not only want direct subclasses you might want to check [this recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576949-find-all-subclasses-of-a-given-class/) to find even subclasses of your subclasses (I also implemented it in a 3rd party extension package of mine: [`iteration_utilities.itersubclasses`](https://iteration-utilities.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/itersubclasses.html)).

Answer (score 1):

Although it is technically possible to perform *call by name* in Python, I strongly advice not to do that. The cleanest way is probably using a dictionary:

```
trans = { 'A' : A, 'B' : B }

def initO(inp):
    cons = trans.get(inp[0])
    if cons is not None:
        return cons(*inp[1:])
```

So here `trans` is a dictionary that maps names on classes (and thus corresponding constructors).

In the `initO` we perform a lookup, if the lookup succeeds, we call the constructor `cons` with the remaining arguments of `inp`.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more about your `A` and `B`, it's hard to say. But this looks like a classic case for a `switch` in a language like C. Python doesn't have a `switch` statement, so the use of a `dict` or `dict`-like construct is used instead.

If you're sure your inputs are clean, you can directly get your classes using the `globals()` function:

```
Os = [globals()[f](x) for (f, x) in inps]
```

If you want to sanitize, you can do something like this:

```
allowed = {'A', 'B'}
Os = [globals()[f](x) for (f, x) in inps if f in allowed]
```

This solution can also be changed if you prefer to have a fixed dictionary and sanitized inputs:

```
allowed = {'A', 'B'}
classname_to_class = {k: v for (k, v) in globals().iteritems() if k in allowed}
# Now, you can have a dict mapping class names to classes without writing 'A': A, 'B': B ...
```

Alternately, if you can prefix all your class definitions, you could even do something like this:

```
classname_to_class = {k[13:]: v for (k, v) in globals().iteritems() if k.startswith('SpecialPrefix'} # 13: is the length of 'SpecialPrefix'
```

This solution allows you to just name your classes with a prefix and have the dictionary automatically populate (after stripping out the special prefix if you so choose). These dictionaries are equivalent to `trans` and `dct` in the other solutions posted here, except without having to manually generate the dictionary.

Unlike the other solutions posted so far, these reduce the likelihood of a transcription error (and the amount of boilerplate code required) in cases where you have a lot more classes than A and B.

Comment: To the down-voter, could you please explain the reasoning behind the down vote? Does this solution not work (aside from when classes are locally defined) or I stated something incorrect? Did I not answer the question? Is there some bad practice I'm employing here without sufficient warning?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is your use of globals() the "call by name" feature that @Willem referred to?

Comment: There are several ways to call things by name in Python (e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061/calling-a-function-of-a-module-from-a-string-with-the-functions-name-in-python shows a few wyas), so I'm not sure which one was being referred to, there. And, depending on your situation, there is nothing wrong with calling by name. I'm going to update my answer with another way of accomplishing the task, more similar to the ones above.

Comment: Edit made. As you can see, these really are the same as the other solutions -- except less laborious/error-prone (for certain classes of errors).

Answer (score 0):

At the risk of drawing more negative fire... we can use metaclasses. This may or may not be suitable for your particular application. Every time you define a subclass of class `O`, you always have an up-to-date list (well, `dict`) of `O`'s subclasses. Oh, and this is written for Python 2 (but can be ported to Python 3).

```
class OMetaclass(type):
    '''This metaclass adds a 'subclasses' attribute to its classes that
    maps subclass name to the class object.'''
    def __init__(cls, name, bases, dct):
        if not hasattr(cls, 'subclasses'):
            cls.subclasses = {}
        else:
            cls.subclasses[name] = cls

        super(OMetaclass, cls).__init__(name, bases, dct)

class O(object):
    __metaclass__ = OMetaclass

### Now, define the rest of your subclasses of O as usual.

class A(O):
    def __init__(self, x): pass

class B(O):
    def __init__(self, x): pass
```

Now, you have a dictionary, `O.subclasses`, that contains all the subclasses of `O`. You can now just do this:

```
Os = [O.subclasses[cls](arg) for (cls, arg) in inps]
```

Now, you don't have to worry about weird prefixes for your classes and you won't need to change your code if you're subclassing `O` already, but you've introduced magic (metaclasses) that may make your program harder to grok.